# How can I run Thanos on Docker?

Tags: docker

I would like to run Thanos od Docker. How can I do that? Now, I'm trying this way:

`sudo docker run --name thanos -d -p 10902:10902 improbable/thanos:master`

but status is: `Exited (0) 10 seconds ago`

As a result of `docker logs thanos`, is:

```
usage: thanos [<flags>] <command> [<args> ...]

A block storage based long-term storage for Prometheus

Flags:
  -h, --help            Show context-sensitive help (also try --help-long and
                    --help-man).
  --version         Show application version.
  --log.level=info  Log filtering level.
  --gcloudtrace.project=GCLOUDTRACE.PROJECT
                    GCP project to send Google Cloud Trace tracings to. If
                    empty, tracing will be disabled.
  --gcloudtrace.sample-factor=1
                    How often we send traces (1/<sample-factor>). If 0 no
                    trace will be sent periodically, unless forced by
                    baggage item. See `pkg/tracing/tracing.go` for details.

Commands:
  [Commands...]
```

No errors found. What's wrong?

Comment: You can not run thanos with out profer configuration as it will run and exit, as it depends on another service like minio, prometheus etc. if you just intrested to get inside your container you can try `sudo docker run --rm --name thanos -it -p 10902:10902 --entrypoint "/bin/sh" improbable/thanos:master` https://github.com/dbluxo/quickstart-thanos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to provide the complete command for thanos, for example this:

```
sudo docker run --name thanos -d -p 10902:10902 improbable/thanos:master --version
```

will print the thanos version and exit the container

explain:

on the image there is an Entrypoint command wich is `thanos` which will run always when starting the container , so if you do not provide any parameters to the `thanos` command you will get the help message from the command and the conatiner will exit normally with exit code `0` since it has done running the provided command

Comment: Ok, but why status is `Exited` but not `Up`? And `docker container ls -a' shows empty PORTS on this container. Do you know why? Is something wrong with port?

Comment: as I said , the container finish running the comand so it exited , and you will find no ports for stopped container. nothing wrong with your docker except you need to provide the parameters to your thanos command